# whenever i try to write a hello world program in c on visual studio i get this

Tags: c, linux

```
cd "/home/luca/c++/.vscode/" && gcc test.c -o test && "/home/luca/c++/.vscode/"test
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   // printf() displays the string inside quotation
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you press Ctrl+S to save your code before running?

Comment: What happens when you manually run the command gcc -o main <filename.c> and the ./main